# Why does my Tiny MCE listbox remain active after being selected?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, listbox, tinymce

I've used a JS plugin to add a listbox to the MCE buttons on the WordPress editor.

The listbox works as expected - it drops down and when you click on one of the options, it inserts the text. However, after the first use, the list box remains active, so all the options are blue (because of my admin theme), and have no hover effect.

This appears to be because the class `mce-active` is added to each drop down after the first use, and then not removed. Why is this? I've not told it to do so.

My PHP is:

```
// add new buttons
    add_filter( 'mce_buttons', 'myplugin_register_buttons' );

    function myplugin_register_buttons( $buttons ) {
       array_push( $buttons, 'separator', 'bf_rsvp_person_details', 'bf_rsvp_event_details' );
       return $buttons;
    }

    // Load the TinyMCE plugin : editor_plugin.js (wp2.5)
    add_filter( 'mce_external_plugins', 'myplugin_register_tinymce_javascript' );

    function myplugin_register_tinymce_javascript( $plugin_array ) {
       $plugin_array['bf_rsvp_person_details'] = plugins_url( '/jquery/bf_rsvp_personal_details.js',__FILE__ );
       $plugin_array['bf_rsvp_event_details'] = plugins_url( '/jquery/bf_rsvp_event_details.js',__FILE__ );
       return $plugin_array;
    }
```

and my JS for one of the plugins (the other is functionally identical) is:

```
tinymce.PluginManager.add('bf_rsvp_event_details', function(editor) {

    editor.addButton('bf_rsvp_event_details', {
         type: 'listbox',
                    text: 'Event Details',                   
                    icon: false,
                    tooltip: 'Insert the event details',
                    classes: 'bf_rsvp_list_box',
                    onselect: function(e) {
                    }, 
                    values: [

                        {text: 'Event name', onclick : function() {
                            editor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, '#eventname#');
                        }},
                        {text: 'Location', onclick : function() {
                            editor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, '#evenlocation#');
                        }},
                        {text: 'Date & Time', onclick : function() {
                            editor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, '#evendate#');
                        }},
                        {text: 'Description', onclick : function() {
                            editor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, '#eventdescription#');
                        }},



                    ]

                });

});
```